# Sending an HTML email with base64 image as part of the HTML

Tags: base64, html-email

I'm trying to send an email, with HTML content that includes an image tag,

for example:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU...gAAASwAAAAmCC" />
```

unfortunately none of the mail client i'm using support this kind of "src" on image tag.

tried to Google it, it seems as known issue, but none of the answers was good for me.

**by the way**, i'm using AngularJS to bind the model to the html content, then pass it as an html string

to the WebApi controller, and then send it with an Smtp client.

Hope someone can help me solved this somehow,

Thanks,

Nadav S.

Comment: What does the HTML look like when it is received by your backend controller ?

Comment: As a string that contains a valid html, without angularjs attributes...if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. Most clients do not support the "data:" url and even if they do, the size of the binary you can embed is very limited. Barely enough for a thumbnail, not enough for a real picture.

The correct way to do this is with mime multipart/related and the "cid:" url. Then one part contains the HTML and the other part contains the base64 encoded picture. The image part contains a header with a field called "Content-ID". The value is any unique string surrounded by <>. For example:

```
Content-ID: <xxxyyy>
```

In your HTML you use the following code:

```
<img src="cid:xxxyyy"/>
```

See rfc-2392 for the full specification.